# persistance of javascript functions within an object

Tags: javascript

I have some functions that only return values if some underlying 'stuff' in the dom has changes, as so:

```
    function getFoo() {

        if (typeof this.prev === "undefined") {
            this.prev = null;
        }
 // calculate x

        if (x != this.prev) {
            this.prev = x;
        return this.prev;
        } else {
        return;
        }
    }
```

`foo` returns none if the computer var `x` hasnt changed. This seems to work fine when called from the console.

Next, I wrapped this in an object so i could sequentially call similar functions:

```
function bar () {
    this.plugins = {
        foo: getFoo
    };

    for (var attr in this.plugins) {
        if (this.plugins.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            console.log(this.plugins[attr]());
        }
    }
```

The strange thing is that when I call `bar()` now, the underlying functions (such as `getFoo`) always return values -- even if the underlying stuff in the dom hasnt changed. it seems that the functions are destroyed upon use (in the `plugin` object) -- how can i persist these?

Comment: can you give an example of when/how you call bar()?

Comment: FYI, functions *always* return a value; just `return` will return `undefined`.

Comment: Your description is very lacking, without showing more code and more context it's almost impossible to know what context `this` has in all these functions. And I would bet my bottom dollar that it's a `this` scope issue. Try changing the invoking of those function to `.call(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you call `bar()`, it calls

```
this.plugin.getFoo();
```

so `this` inside `getFoo` will reference `this.plugins`.

You initialize `this.plugin` with a new object every time you call `bar()`:

```
this.plugins = {
    foo: getFoo
};
```

---

Honestly your structure seems to quite confusing. Do you know that `this` inside the `bar()` function refers to the `window` object? You are "polluting" the global namespace with that. Same for `getFoo` if you are calling it directly.

Maybe you should have more something like this:

```
var bar = {
    plugins: {foo: getFoo},
    run: function() {
        for (var attr in this.plugins) {
            if (this.plugins.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                console.log(this.plugins[attr]());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

the you can call:

```
bar.run();
```

---

Another way of having persistent and private data between function calls is to use a closure:

```
var getFoo = (function() {
    var prev = null;

    return function(x){
        if (x != prev) {
            prev = x;
            return prev;
        }
    }
}());
```

Here the function return by the immediate function closes over `prev`. No matter where you assign `getFoo` it will have always access to `prev` and it does not overwrite any other `prev` variable in some other scope.

I think it is also better when you pass `x` to the function.

Comment: Thank you - its sort of hard to explain the whole context, but i think the function closure refactor will work!

Answer (score 1):

So everytime you call "bar()" you are overwriting the plugins attribute of your object.  Just put a simple check in before redefining the plugins attribute, like this:

```
function bar () {
  if (typeof this.plugins === "undefined") {
    this.plugins = {
      foo: getFoo
    };
  }

  for (var attr in this.plugins) {
      if (this.plugins.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
          console.log(this.plugins[attr]());
      }
  }
...
```